# Stochastic process is measurable $\Rightarrow$ each component is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Given that $$(t,\omega)\mapsto X(t,\omega)$$ is measurable, how can I reason that $\omega\mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is also measurable?

Comment: This is included in the proof of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do we need sigma additivity here?

Comment: No measure are involved in this part of then proof.